# Why does the Pokémon count show one more than the actual Pokémon I have?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have 11 Pokémon, none duplicate. But the count at the top shows 12.

[image]

Is this a bug, or does it count the Pokémon in the egg, too?

Comment: *Maybe there's a Gastly haunting you...?*

Comment: this is 100% the egg. Ive watched this count change as Ive picked up and hatched eggs.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what kind of area/region do you live in that you found Pinsir, Ponyta, Growlithe, Chansey, and Sandshrew?

Comment: @Captain I literally live behind a zoo/animal park separated by a 500m forest area `:)`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**'Total Pokémon' is a count of *all* currently held pokémon *and* eggs being hatched**

In the example you give, you are currently holding 11 pokémon, and 1 egg in an incubator. The given pokémon count is 12.

This is likely in order to prevent bugs related to issues that would otherwise arise when you have a full box of 250 pokémon, and could proceed to hatch more, through eggs.

It is worth addressing that this is a *total held pokémon* count, not a count of *unique* pokémon. If you *did* have duplicates in your box, they would also contribute to your final count.

Comment: I initally thought I transferred a pokémon accidentally to the Professor, but I was wrong. Transferring pokémons the the Prof. reduces the count. *You are right with the egg being counted*.

Answer (score 0):

It's the eggs for sure. I currently have 66 Pokemon and 8 eggs but my count at the top of the screen says 74/250. It definitely counts your eggs.